# Gradle moowork node plugin

Tags: node.js, gradle, npm, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I have NodeJS/NPM installed in my linux and windows machine. I do not want to download this again. I am getting error while building UI code using NodeJS.

```
Execution failed for task ':my-war:npmSetup'.
>  A problem occurred starting process 'command 'npm.cmd''
```

There are variants to set `nodeDir` and `npmDir`. I could not use them inside

```
node{
  ...
  ...
}
```

`node{..}` only has working directory settings. Please suggest how to configure already installed node to the build.

Answer (score 1):

See this post on the plugin issues list: https://github.com/srs/gradle-node-plugin/issues/119

You need to point the distBaseUrl at your local installation of nodejs (i.e., the folder where node.exe is located on your machine).

```
node{
  ...
  distBaseUrl = "file:C:/DirectoryName/nodejs"
  ...
}
```

Also ensure that nodejs and npm are included in your PATH.